# jquery dataTables does not render properly when it is used in Tab control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, datatables, tabs

I am using jquery dataTables 1.10.24 with jQuery JavaScript Library v3.6.0. This works very well except one case, when I am rendering the table in the Tab control the column headers are not rendered correctly. But when I click on the column header for sorting, it gets adjusted and occupy the entire layout. Please find the screen shot attached. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I used the below code render the table. This works fine if the table is not rendered inside the Tab control.

```
$('.table').dataTable({
    colReorder: true,
    searching: true,
    pageLength: 10,
    lengthChange: true,
    paging: true,
    conditionalPaging: true,
    lengthMenu: [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
    order: [],
    scrollX: true,
    columnDefs: [{ targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false, }]
});
```

I am unable to find any articles about this issue. Please help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY0Xd.png

Comment: Can you please show your html code ?

Comment: Take a look at [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html)

Comment: Thanks lot. The above comment is the ANSWER for my question. :)